# Hive query, better option to self join

Tags: database, hive

So I am working with a hive table that is set up as so:

id (Int), mapper (String), mapperId (Int)

Basically a single Id can have multiple mapperIds, one per mapper such as an example below:

ID (1) mapper(MAP1) mapperId(123)

ID (1) mapper(MAP2) mapperId(1234)

ID (1) mapper(MAP3) mapperId(12345)

ID (2) mapper(MAP2) mapperId(10)

ID (2) mapper(MAP3) mapperId(12)

I want to return the list of mapperIds associated to each unique ID. So for the above example I would want the below returned as a single row.

1, 123, 1234, 12345

2, null, 10, 12

The mapper Strings are known, so I was thinking of doing a self join for every mapper string I am interested in, but I was wondering if there was a more optimal solution?

Comment: In your `mapper` column, is there only `MAP1`, `MAP2`, and `MAP3` or are there other possible values? Also, what do you mean by `list`?  Array?

Answer (score 2):

If the assumption that the `mapper` column is distinct with respect to a given `ID` is correct, you could collect the `mapper` column and the `mapperid` column to a Map using [brickhouse collect](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/tree/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect).  You can clone the repo from that link and build the jar with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).

**Query:**

```
add jar /complete/path/to/jar/brickhouse-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

select id
      ,id_map['MAP1'] as mapper1
      ,id_map['MAP2'] as mapper2
      ,id_map['MAP3'] as mapper3
from (
      select id
            ,collect(mapper, mapperid) as id_map
      from some_table
      group by id
     ) x
```

**Output:**

```
| id | mapper1 | mapper2 | mapper3 |
------------------------------------
  1    123      1234       12345
  2             10         12
```